# Free space turned unusable when dual booting Ubuntu with Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

I bought a Sony Vaio VPCF11S1E which came with Windows 8. I installed Windows 10 and now I tried to dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. But after creating the swap area the free space turned to unusable! I reverted and now it's normal again. It's seems that after creating a fourth partition I cannot add another! so I'm stuck with Windows 10.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Create logical partitions.

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If your disk partitioning is MSDOS instead of GPT, you are limited to only four primary partitions.  The usual solution is to make the fourth partition an extended partition, and then you can add logical partitions within the extended partition, and Ubuntu does not care if its partitions are logical or primary.  Your situation is odd since all machines with Windows 8 preinstalled I thought were UEFI on a GPT partitioned disk.  Anyway, small shops can put Windows 10 on an MSDOS disk, and you then live with the limitations.

---

Try the Google search:

> convert legacy Windows 10 to UEFI
>   The link [third item](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1eXD30Fox4)  has some detailed text on the "more" as well as a video.

Ron Smith's gpt fdisk also has some possibilities, but whatever you do, backup everything first, most of the instructions assume you will wipe the disk and recreate everything.  Assume the worst.  It would be far easier to free up some space at the end of the disk, add an extended partition, and then add logical partitions for the Ubuntu install.

I'm faced with a similar problem, a legacy Windows 7 upgraded to Windows 10, but I have a Lenovo which can boot either legacy or UEFI without switching things in the UEFI settings, so I can boot UEFI Ubuntu off a second GPT disk in the disk caddy when I want to (just cannot boot Windows that way, but I don't care).

Comment: Is there a way I can change/convert the the disk partitioning from MSDOS to GPT?

Comment: @M1i20 No, changing the partition table will effectively format the storage device.

Comment: @MichaelLindman Does that mean I'll loose all my data? it doesn't matter to me as long I change the disk partitioning. I really need to dual boot Ubuntu!

Comment: @M1i205 It does but I suggest you create a backup of your system so you don't loose anything if you decide to do it.

Comment: @MichaelLindman How to change the disk partitioning from MSDOS to GPT?